# How to test if 2 proportions from the same sample are significantly different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I asked a random group of people from an organisation a question. I then have a proportion of favorable responses (e.g. 80% of 100 participants gave favorable responses).

6 months later, I asked another random group of people from the same organisation, the same question. I then have a proportion of favorable responses (e.g. 85% of 120 participants gave favorable responses).

The question (e.g. the organisation was a good place to work in) was in likert scale: strongly disagree, disagree, neutral, agree, strongly agree. Favorable responses are number of responses to agree and strongly agree.

How do I know if the difference between the first time point and second time point on the same question is significantly different? What test can I use for it? I tied calculating z-score for 2 Population Proportions but am not too sure if it is the right stats to use.

Comment: @IWS the link was posted as an answer. I converted to a comment as the OP posted the same answer twice.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than simplifying your data by splitting it into favourable and not, keep it as scores on your 5 point likert scale.

Then you can do a repeated measures t test to determine whether there is a difference between the two question times.

Then when you interpret the results you can then answer the question **how much** more/less favourable were the scores? Rather than simply saying the proportion changed.

Edit: it's not clear from your question, but if the two sets are from different employees rather than asking the same employees twice, then you'd need to use an independent samples t test instead of repeated measures t test